# Maya Python .batchRender says "file is invalid"

Tags: python, rendering, render, maya

This is my code to kick of the render of a scene.

```
cmds.batchRender()
cmds.batchRender( r'C:\Users\marvin\Desktop\Proxy\Game\Vegetation\Tree\Tree.mb' )
```

when I run it all I get is:

```
# Error: Object C:\Users\marvin\Desktop\Proxy\Game\Vegetation\Tree\Tree.mb is invalid
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 21, in renderImage
# TypeError: Object C:\Users\marvin\Desktop\Proxy\Game\Vegetation\Tree\Tree.mb is invalid #
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It should work by passing the file path using the `filename` named parameter:

```py
cmds.batchRender(filename=r'C:\Users\marvin\Desktop\Proxy\Game\Vegetation\Tree\Tree.mb')
```

Edit: This actually doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: `// Result: There is currently no render to cancel //
// Result: There is currently no render to cancel // `.

Unfortunatly all I get now is this. It seems to be not detecting the actual file it is supposed to render. Instead its trying to kill the renderjob like it should happen when there is no file specified

Comment: My bad, I think I misread the docs, will update the answer, apologies.